# Linq2Sql context.SubmitChanges() generates "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql

I have a web service that is using Linq2Sql to insert records into a database.

The web service method is below:

```
public class WS_StreamCrossing : IStreamCrossing
{
    public string SendStreamCrossingSurveys(List<Survey> mySurveyList)
    {
        if (mySurveyList == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("mySurveyList");
        }

        string result = "Failed";


        using (StreamCrossingDataContext myObjectContext = GetDBContext())
        {
            foreach (Survey myPassedSurvey in mySurveyList)
            {
                // Check for existing Survey with matching data (PRNo, MP, FWVersion, CulvertID, SurveyDate)
                Survey myMatchingSurvey = myObjectContext.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PRNo == myPassedSurvey.PRNo && x.MP == myPassedSurvey.MP && x.FWVersion == myPassedSurvey.FWVersion && x.CulvertID == myPassedSurvey.CulvertID && x.SurveyDate == myPassedSurvey.SurveyDate);
                if (myMatchingSurvey != null)
                {

                    myMatchingSurvey.AdjacentLandowner = myPassedSurvey.AdjacentLandowner;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ApproachLengthLeft = myPassedSurvey.ApproachLengthLeft;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ApproachLengthRight = myPassedSurvey.ApproachLengthRight;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ApproachSlopeLeft = myPassedSurvey.ApproachSlopeLeft;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ApproachSlopeRight = myPassedSurvey.ApproachSlopeRight;
                    myMatchingSurvey.BackwaterComments = myPassedSurvey.BackwaterComments;
                    myMatchingSurvey.CalculatedPassability = myPassedSurvey.CalculatedPassability;
                    myMatchingSurvey.County = myPassedSurvey.County;
                    myMatchingSurvey.CrossingType = myPassedSurvey.CrossingType;
                    myMatchingSurvey.CrushedLocation = myPassedSurvey.CrushedLocation;
                    myMatchingSurvey.CrushedPercent = myPassedSurvey.CrushedPercent;
                    //myMatchingSurvey.CulvertID = myPassedSurvey.CulvertID;
                    myMatchingSurvey.DefinedPassability = myPassedSurvey.DefinedPassability;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ErosionExtent = myPassedSurvey.ErosionExtent;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ErosionNotes = myPassedSurvey.ErosionNotes;
                    myMatchingSurvey.FillDepthDownStream = myPassedSurvey.FillDepthDownStream;
                    myMatchingSurvey.FillDepthUpStream = myPassedSurvey.FillDepthUpStream;
                    myMatchingSurvey.FutureComments = myPassedSurvey.FutureComments;
                    myMatchingSurvey.FutureVisit = myPassedSurvey.FutureVisit;
                    //myMatchingSurvey.FWVersion = myPassedSurvey.FWVersion;
                    myMatchingSurvey.GeneralCondition = myPassedSurvey.GeneralCondition;
                    myMatchingSurvey.HeadChangeComments = myPassedSurvey.HeadChangeComments;
                    myMatchingSurvey.InletStructure = myPassedSurvey.InletStructure;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsBackwatered = myPassedSurvey.IsBackwatered;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsErosionCorrectable = myPassedSurvey.IsErosionCorrectable;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsErosionPresent = myPassedSurvey.IsErosionPresent;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsHeadChanged = myPassedSurvey.IsHeadChanged;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsOvertopping = myPassedSurvey.IsOvertopping;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsPerched = myPassedSurvey.IsPerched;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsPrioritySite = myPassedSurvey.IsPrioritySite;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsRustedThrough = myPassedSurvey.IsRustedThrough;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsScourPoolPresent = myPassedSurvey.IsScourPoolPresent;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsSubstrateEntireLength = myPassedSurvey.IsSubstrateEntireLength;
                    myMatchingSurvey.IsUpstreamPondPresent = myPassedSurvey.IsUpstreamPondPresent;
                    myMatchingSurvey.Latitude = myPassedSurvey.Latitude;
                    myMatchingSurvey.LocationComments = myPassedSurvey.LocationComments;
                    myMatchingSurvey.LocationOfLowPoint = myPassedSurvey.LocationOfLowPoint;
                    myMatchingSurvey.Longitude = myPassedSurvey.Longitude;
                    //myMatchingSurvey.MP = myPassedSurvey.MP;
                    myMatchingSurvey.NonNativeInvasiveSpecies = myPassedSurvey.NonNativeInvasiveSpecies;
                    myMatchingSurvey.Observers = myPassedSurvey.Observers;
                    myMatchingSurvey.OutletStructure = myPassedSurvey.OutletStructure;
                    myMatchingSurvey.OutletType = myPassedSurvey.OutletType;
                    myMatchingSurvey.OvertoppingComments = myPassedSurvey.OvertoppingComments;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PassabilityComments = myPassedSurvey.PassabilityComments;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PerchHeight = myPassedSurvey.PerchHeight;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PhotoDownstream = myPassedSurvey.PhotoDownstream;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PhotoInlet = myPassedSurvey.PhotoInlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PhotoOutlet = myPassedSurvey.PhotoOutlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PhotoRoadApproachLeft = myPassedSurvey.PhotoRoadApproachLeft;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PhotoRoadApproachRight = myPassedSurvey.PhotoRoadApproachRight;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PhotoUpstream = myPassedSurvey.PhotoUpstream;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PluggedLocation = myPassedSurvey.PluggedLocation;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PluggedPercent = myPassedSurvey.PluggedPercent;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PriorityComments = myPassedSurvey.PriorityComments;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PriorityReason = myPassedSurvey.PriorityReason;
                    //myMatchingSurvey.PRNo = myPassedSurvey.PRNo;
                    myMatchingSurvey.PtID = myPassedSurvey.PtID;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RefMiles = myPassedSurvey.RefMiles;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RiffleBankfullWidth = myPassedSurvey.RiffleBankfullWidth;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RiffleMeasuredWith = myPassedSurvey.RiffleMeasuredWith;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RiffleSubstrate = myPassedSurvey.RiffleSubstrate;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RiffleWaterDepth = myPassedSurvey.RiffleWaterDepth;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RiffleWaterVelocity = myPassedSurvey.RiffleWaterVelocity;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RiffleWettedWidth = myPassedSurvey.RiffleWettedWidth;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RoadCondition = myPassedSurvey.RoadCondition;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RoadName = myPassedSurvey.RoadName;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RoadSurface = myPassedSurvey.RoadSurface;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RoadWidth = myPassedSurvey.RoadWidth;
                    myMatchingSurvey.RunOffPath = myPassedSurvey.RunOffPath;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ScourPoolDepth = myPassedSurvey.ScourPoolDepth;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ScourPoolLength = myPassedSurvey.ScourPoolLength;
                    myMatchingSurvey.ScourPoolWidth = myPassedSurvey.ScourPoolWidth;
                    myMatchingSurvey.SiteID = myPassedSurvey.SiteID;
                    myMatchingSurvey.SlopeDownStream = myPassedSurvey.SlopeDownStream;
                    myMatchingSurvey.SlopeUpStream = myPassedSurvey.SlopeUpStream;
                    myMatchingSurvey.SpeciesObserved = myPassedSurvey.SpeciesObserved;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StreamFlow = myPassedSurvey.StreamFlow;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureEmbeddedDepthInlet = myPassedSurvey.StructureEmbeddedDepthInlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureEmbeddedDepthOutlet = myPassedSurvey.StructureEmbeddedDepthOutlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureInterior = myPassedSurvey.StructureInterior;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureShape = myPassedSurvey.StructureShape;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureWaterDepthInlet = myPassedSurvey.StructureWaterDepthInlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureWaterDepthOutlet = myPassedSurvey.StructureWaterDepthOutlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityInlet = myPassedSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityInlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityMeasured = myPassedSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityMeasured;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityMeasuredWith = myPassedSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityMeasuredWith;
                    myMatchingSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityOutlet = myPassedSurvey.StructureWaterVelocityOutlet;
                    myMatchingSurvey.SubstrateInStructure = myPassedSurvey.SubstrateInStructure;
                    //myMatchingSurvey.SurveyDate = myPassedSurvey.SurveyDate;
                    myMatchingSurvey.UpstreamPondLength = myPassedSurvey.UpstreamPondLength;
                    myMatchingSurvey.UpstreamPondWidth = myPassedSurvey.UpstreamPondWidth;
                    myMatchingSurvey.VegetationDitchLeft = myPassedSurvey.VegetationDitchLeft;
                    myMatchingSurvey.VegetationDitchRight = myPassedSurvey.VegetationDitchRight;
                    myMatchingSurvey.Waterway = myPassedSurvey.Waterway;


                    // Delete all Erosions
                    myObjectContext.Erosions.DeleteAllOnSubmit(myMatchingSurvey.Erosions);

                    // Assign new Erosions
                    myMatchingSurvey.Erosions = myPassedSurvey.Erosions;

                    // Delete all Spans
                    myObjectContext.Spans.DeleteAllOnSubmit(myMatchingSurvey.Spans);

                    // Assign new Spans
                    myMatchingSurvey.Spans = myPassedSurvey.Spans;

                }
                else
                {
                    myObjectContext.Surveys.InsertOnSubmit(myPassedSurvey);
                }
            }

            myObjectContext.SubmitChanges();
            result = "Success";

        }

        return result;
    }
```

When I send a basic test through the web service to add a new record, it generates an error at the `myObjectContext.SubmitChanges()`:

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     Source=System.Data.Linq
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Linq.Binary.ToArray()
>          at System.Data.Linq.DBConvert.ChangeType(Object value, Type type)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlTypeSystem.ProviderBase.GetParameterValue(SqlType type, Object value)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlTypeSystem.ProviderBase.InitializeParameter(ProviderType type, DbParameter parameter, Object value)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.AssignParameters(DbCommand cmd, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parms, Object[] userArguments, Object lastResult)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
>          at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
>          at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject item)
>          at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item)
>          at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
>          at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
>          at DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE.WS_StreamCrossing.SendStreamCrossingSurveys(List`1 mySurveyList) in C:\TFS Projects\DNR.CulvertInventory\Main\Src\Code\DNR.CulvertInventory\DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE\WS_StreamCrossing.svc.cs:line 255
>          at DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE.WS_StreamCrossing.SendStreamCrossingSurvey(Survey mySurvey) in C:\TFS Projects\DNR.CulvertInventory\Main\Src\Code\DNR.CulvertInventory\DNR.CulvertInventory.SERVICE\WS_StreamCrossing.svc.cs:line 273
>          at SyncInvokeSendStreamCrossingSurvey(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>     InnerException:

The thing is, this error does not occur when I run tests against the service using a Visual Studio test project.  Here is an example test that is trying the same thing and works just fine:

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost(testDirectory)]
[UrlToTest(testURL)]
public void CanCreateNewSurveyWithErosionsAndSpans()
{
    string expected = "Success";

    SERVICE.Survey mySurvey = CreateBaseSurveyObject();

    SERVICE.Erosion myFirstErosion = CreateErosionObject(2);
    mySurvey.Erosions.Add(myFirstErosion);

    SERVICE.Erosion mySecondErosion = CreateErosionObject(2);
    mySurvey.Erosions.Add(mySecondErosion);

    SERVICE.Span myFirstSpan = CreateSpanObject(2);
    mySurvey.Spans.Add(myFirstSpan);

    SERVICE.Span mySecondSpan = CreateSpanObject(2);
    mySurvey.Spans.Add(mySecondSpan);

    string actual = target.SendStreamCrossingSurvey(mySurvey);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Any ideas?

In response to questions, here is some more data.

This is the `GetDBContext()` method:

```
private StreamCrossingDataContext GetDBContext()
{
    SERVICE.StreamCrossingDataContext db = new SERVICE.StreamCrossingDataContext();

    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();

    options.LoadWith<SERVICE.Survey>(x => x.Erosions);
    options.LoadWith<SERVICE.Survey>(x => x.Spans);

    db.LoadOptions = options;

    return db;
}
```

Comment: What does GetDBContext() method returning?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing all the datatypes of the property, but could you possibly be setting a non null reference to null in one the assignments ?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I have updated the question with the GetDBContext() method implementation.

Comment: @user957902 This is setup as a SOAP web service and the object that I pass in the actual "Survey" object direct from the Linq2Sql DMBL file.  I don't believe it will let me actually set a non null value type to null.  But I have looked, and as far as I can see, any fields where null is not allowed for value types, it is putting in the default value (i.e., 0 for int, "" for string, etc).